# How to iterate an array every 30 items

Tags: ruby

I have an array of products with 234 items.
I need to create another array with a pagination (every 10 items)
example:

```
[
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
...
]
```

How can I solve this?
I've tried in_groups_of but I don't have success.

Comment: every 10 items or 30?

Comment: _"I don't have success"_ – what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [each_slice](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice)

Whenever you have an array problem, check the `Enumerable`. [in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) is a Rails method and uses `each_slice` under the hood.

Comment: I suggest you add an example with code, the example having, say, 12 (rather than 234) items to be reduced to 4 groups of 3 (rather than 10).

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
[*1..34].each_slice(10).to_a

# =>
# [
#   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
#   [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
#   [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
#   [31, 32, 33, 34]
# ]
```